# How to activate comment moderations

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I have added a facebook comment social plug in box here: www.example.com/guestbook.html

I have included the following line of code on the page:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="370981509585131"/>
```

I do have this SDK code at the top of the page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=370981509585131";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

So I have the SDK with the `AppID` in there, and I added the code as instructed on [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)
page but I have not been able to moderate the comments from the [comment moderation tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments?)

Comment: Supposedly it is as simple as having your fb:admins like the page and have the og meta tag for fb:admins defined on the page where the comments are getting entered.  However, I cannot figure out why I cannot moderate comments either.  I hope someone has a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have wrong value for `fb:admins` OpenGraph meta tag:

> Object at URL 'http://www.forumgoesmody.com/guestbook.html' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value '10100218701442679' for property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.

Request to `http://graph.facebook.com/10100218701442679` return `false`

You should fix the errors outlined in [Object Debugger tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) for URL of page your Comments Social Plugin located on. Once you fixed the errors you should be able to moderate your comments in [Comments Moderation tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments)

You can simply remove `fb:admins`, if only Administrators of Application (`fb:app_id`) should be able to moderate the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could check my answer to similar probem at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9073966/1134615. Not sure wether thats a proper solution but that works for me. Also, remove:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="370981509585131"/>
```

as it is already stated in js.